# no such table: tablename in sqlite even after initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

i am new to ios dev and i am having the following problem:
i initialized the tables i needed, and when i try to execute a query to any of the tables i get the "no such table" error, here is the steps and code:

```
        -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Function called to create a copy of the database if needed.
                [[SQLiteUtilities sharedSQLiteManager] initializationDatabase];
                return YES;
            }

            and here is the implementation:

         -(void)initializationDatabase {
                NSString *path = [self databaseFilePath];
                BOOL isExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];

                if (isExists) return;

                FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
                if ([db open] == NO) {
                    return;
                } 
                NSString *sql =
                @"CREATE TABLE albums("
                "albumid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                "directory CHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
                "albumname CHAR(32) NOT NULL,"
                "count INT NOT NULL,"
                "orderid INT NOT NULL"
                ");"

                "CREATE TABLE photos("
                "photoid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                "albumid INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,"
                "filename CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT \"\","
                "originalname CHAR(50) DEFAULT \"\","
                "addtime INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,"
                "createtime INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,"
                "filesize INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0"
                ");";
                //[db executeQuery:sql1];
                [db executeQuery:sql];
                [db close];
            }

    and when i try to add anything as follows i get the "no such table:albums" error:

- (AlbumsUtilities *)createAlbumWithName:(NSString *)name {
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self databaseFilePath]];
    if (![db open]) return nil;
    NSString *directory = createRandomAlbumDirectory();

    int maxid = 0;
    BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO albums(directory,albumname,count,orderid) VALUES(?,?,0,?)", directory,name,@(maxid)];
    AlbumsUtilities *album = nil;
    if (success) {
       ....(not getting here of course)
    }
    [db close];
    return album;
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is your sqlite file present in document directory?

Comment: yes i have checked many times, and i even deleted and checked if it is being created again just in case.
i tried dropping the table, clearing the simulator, nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this two function for initialize db .

**ADD Blank File .sqlite extension**

```
- (void)createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"%@",[self getDBPath]);

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self getDBPath]];
    if (success){
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:[self getDBPath] error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


-(NSString *)getDBPath{
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    return  dbPath;
}
```

**After Initialize create table**

```
-(void)createTable{
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[self getDBPath]];
    [database open];
    [database executeUpdate:"your query"];
    [database close];
}
```

**Calling**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Function called to create a copy of the database if needed.
            [[SQLiteUtilities sharedSQLiteManager] createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
       [[SQLiteUtilities sharedSQLiteManager] createTable];
}
```

Comment: Any issue with this function .

Comment: no i have tried just now and it works!
thank you so much but i am still new so i might need some time to figure out what the problem was, can u help me with that?
thank you very much!

Comment: it is because your have initializing the  database in wrong place.  si

Comment: i tried to clear everything and start over but when i did i got the following error:  writable database file with message 'The file “db.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. this happens when i try to "createCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded" any ideas?

Comment: "writable database file with message 'The file “db.sqlite” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file" is my error message.

Comment: you need to add black sqlite file with or if your have already added then rename db.sqlite with your name

Comment: i didn't get that can u please explain more i am new to ios dev, thank you!

Comment: did you add sqlite file  in your project ?

Comment: ah now i get it, i just created it programmatically in case it does not exist and it works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@Try this:

```
 Bool isSuccess = YES;
 if (sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    { 

        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactTable (albumid integer primary key autoincrement ,directory CHAR(20) NOT NULL, albumname CHAR(32) NOT NULL, albumname CHAR(32) NOT NULL, count INT NOT NULL, orderid INT NOT NULL);";


        if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
            != SQLITE_OK)
        {         

            sqlite3_close(db);
            isSuccess = NO;

        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
        return  isSuccess;
    }
    else {            

        sqlite3_close(db);
        isSuccess = NO;


    }
}


sqlite3_close(db);
NSLog(@"Albums Table Created");
return isSuccess;
```